# How to associate two tables through third in Sequelize.js ?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables: `sites`, `users` which are associated through table `links` by custom fields like `JOIN links ON links.links.Sourceindex = sites.id AND links.Sourcetable = 'SITES' AND links.Contactindex = 'USER_ID'` Is it possible to do in Sequelize ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Without knowing more details about what queries you're trying to perform, maybe these model files would work.

users.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => sequelize.define('users', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    first_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    last_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'users',
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: models => {
            models.users.belongsToMany(models.sites, {
                through: 'links',
                foreignKey: 'contact_index'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

sites.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => sequelize.define('sites', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    url: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'sites',
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: models => {
            models.sites.belongsToMany(models.users, {
                through: 'links',
                foreignKey: 'source_index'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Here's the relevant part in the documentation:

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations